# Mule Facebook Samples Invalid redirect error

Tags: facebook, mule

I have seen a lot of these errors all over the net with different developer framework

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}

I am using Mule ESB to post a comment on a wall but get this error. I have used localhost and the IP address of my PC but nothing seems to work. I am behind a proxy server so not sure if that is the problem. It also seems that Facebook has chaned the UI of the apps page as a lot of sample refer to pages that do not exist anymore.

How do I get my Facebook page to accept my auth and then post using Mule.

Regards.

Jaco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured Facebook properly? They tend to change their app system every few months, so any example is usually outdated. The following works with my test app (just tests auth, does not save token):

FB App:

```
Settings 
-> Basic
-> Add Platform
-> App on Facebook
-> Canvas URL: http://localhost:3000/
```

Mule:

```
<facebook:config-with-oauth name="Facebook" appId="${id}" appSecret="${secret}" doc:name="Facebook">
    <facebook:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="3000" remotePort="3000"></facebook:oauth-callback-config>        
</facebook:config-with-oauth>    

<flow name="authorize"> 
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="3000" path="authorize"></http:inbound-endpoint>  
    <facebook:authorize config-ref="Facebook"></facebook:authorize>  
</flow>
```

If you have a proxy / port forwarding in your environment, you should add the remotePort option explicitly. I run my Mule inside a virtual machine, and it produces the invalid url error without it.

Comment: Thanks for the help Anton. I have done as you stated on Facebook but I still get the same result. I added the http://localhost:8080/ to my facebook app platform

Comment: `<facebook:config-with-oauth name="Facebook" appId="..." appSecret="..." doc:name="Facebook" scope="publish_stream">
        <facebook:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8080"/>
    </facebook:config-with-oauth>
    <flow name="Authorization" doc:name="Authorization">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <facebook:authorize config-ref="Facebook" doc:name="Facebook"/>`

Comment: Seems you don't have the remotePort option included, could be due to that. See my updated answer.

Comment: Dude you rock !!! Thank you. It was the missing remote port. It now sends the requests to Facebook. But now I have another error as it seems you can not use this behind a proxy server. Not sure if this is fixed. I will ask a new question.